# how to use recursion for LCSS in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, recursion

**LCSS**
[LCSS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tJiA8.jpg)

**My code**

```
def Distance(P1,P2,R=6378137):#
    lon1=P1[1];lon2=P2[1]
    lat1=P1[0];lat2=P2[0]
    dist =  R*math.acos(1-(math.pow((math.sin((90-lat1)*math.pi/180)*math.cos(lon1*math.pi/180)-math.sin((90-lat2)*math.pi/180)*math.cos(lon2*math.pi/180)),2)\
                         +math.pow((math.sin((90-lat1)*math.pi/180)*math.sin(lon1*math.pi/180)-math.sin((90-lat2)*math.pi/180)*math.sin(lon2*math.pi/180)),2)\
                         +math.pow((math.cos((90-lat1)*math.pi/180)-math.cos((90-lat2)*math.pi/180)),2))/2)
    return round(dist,2)

def LCSS(A,B,e=500,f=5):
    if len(A)*len(B)==0:
        return 0
    elif Disance(A[-1],B[-1)<e and abs(len(A)-len(B))<f:
        return LCSS()+1
    else:
        return max(LCSS(A[:-1],B),LCSS(A,B[:-1]))
```

---

**The question(s)**
I have no idea the function of LCSS because the function is running all the time in my code, rather than to return a N(int) < max(len(A),len(B)).
Thanks!